# Print a dictionary based on an ordered list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting

I have sorted a dictionary based on a value within that dictionary. Now, I want to print ordered, relevant aspects of the dictionary, using the sorted list of keys.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
sc = sorted(stats,key=lambda x:(stats[x]['avg length'],x)) #to get a sorted list of keys

for sc in stats:
    print "Name %s, Number: %s, Average length: %s, Max length: %s, Min length: %s" % (sc, stats[sc]["number"],stats[sc]["avg length"], stats[sc]["max length"], stats[sc]["min length"])
```

However, the order of the output does not match the order of my list sc. In fact, I cannot see any pattern with how the values outputted..

Sorry if this is a trivial question--I'm new to python :(

Comment: What is the output? What do you expect? Please give a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is a little backwards. You want to iterate over your ordered keys, not your original dictionary:

```
for key in sc:
    print ... % (key, stats[key], ...
```

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you probably meant to write something like:

```
for s in sc:
    print "Name %s, Number: %s, Average length: %s, Max length: %s, Min length: %s" % (s, stats[s]["number"],stats[s]["avg length"], stats[s]["max length"], stats[s]["min length"])
```

You're replacing the sorted list in the existing for loop assignment.

Comment: yes, that was it--I was confused about what I was iterating over. Thank you!